# Not able to save kable tables in R

Tags: r, plot, export, kable

I'm trying to save a `kableExtra` table, but I only managed to do so by clicking on the "save" button above the image (png or jpeg), which is not ideal...[this is my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870622/plot-a-list-of-tables-vertically-kableextra-and-kable-in-r)

- Ideally, I'd like to export it as a Word file (note that knitting to Word in r-markdown is NOT working)
- I'd also like to be able to export to .png, but [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048818/use-kableextras-kbl-and-save-kable-to-export-table-as-word-table-to-word-do) to save as pdf or png is working

If I try the same thing, I get:

```
packageVersion("kableExtra") 
[1] ‘1.3.4’

> library(webshot)
Warning message:
package ‘webshot’ was built under R version 4.1.3 

> dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
>  
> kableExtra::kbl(dt, caption="Table") %>%
+ kableExtra::kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria") %>% 
+ kableExtra::save_kable("my_latex_table.png") # altern
```

```
Could not load  c:%5CUsers%5Claris%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CTemp%5CRtmpm0UVE0%5Cmy_latex_table524420567fce.html
Error in webshot::webshot(file_temp_html, file, ...) : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
```

Any ideas? **Ideally**, I'd like to be able to export to *both* .doc and .png

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue showed inthe code.  I used `packageVersion("kableExtra")#
[1] ‘1.3.4’`

Comment: Do you want to save it as a png or doc?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do both, @Quinten (if it's a possibility, of course)

Comment: Did you load `webshot`?

Comment: @Quinten , just did that, but it's still not working (edited the post with the output) and, akrun, I'm using the same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It seems updating the `{webshot}` package solve this issue. After installing the `{webshot}` package again, Running the following code simply,

```
library(kableExtra)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

kbl(dt, caption="Table") %>%
kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria") %>% 
save_kable("my_latex_table.png")
```

indeed creates the `my_latex_table.png` in the working directory.

```
packageVersion("webshot")
#> [1] '0.5.4'
```

---

### Old answer

It seems you are not alone facing this issue. There's [an exactly same issue #707](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/707) regarding this erroneous behavior of `{webshot}` (Although the issue is currently closed with a suggested workaround).

I am just describing the suggested workaround from [this issue #707 comment](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/707#issuecomment-1117784367).

At first, save the table in a html file using `save_kable` which will create a html file in your working directory and then pass that html file in `webshot::webshot()` to get a screenshot of the table from that html file, which will create the png file in your working directory.

```
library(kableExtra)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

kbl(dt, caption="Table") %>%
kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria") %>% 
save_kable("my_latex_table.png")


webshot::webshot("my_latex_table.html", file = "my_latex_table.png",
                 selector = ".lightable-classic", expand = 20)
```

Comment: Yes! removing the package and installing it again worked, thank you! But, 2 questions: a) how can I change the size of the exported image? b) is there a way to plot is as a .doc (Word) editable file as well? I couldn't find it! @shafee

Comment: AFAIK, `kableExtra` doesn't work natively with docx output, if your goal is word output, I would recommend you to look into either `{flextable}` or `{huxtable}` pkgs.